# How can I make a java program to understand the user-input "t" as "true" and "f" as "false"(boolean)?

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

I have to code a program, that's working with boolean operators. The first thing this program should do is to ask the user for an operator by "command:". The user can only enter "&&", "||", "!" and "quit". Quit just shuts down the program. The next thing it does is to ask the user for a boolean variable, but here is my problem: The program works perfectly fine with entering "true" or "false", but the task I've got says, the user can only use "t" for "f" as input. So here is my question: How can I make the program to understand "t" as "true" and "f" as "false"?(by the way if the user enters"!" the program just outputs the negation of the first parameter)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner eingabe = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Command: ");
    String command = eingabe.nextLine();

    if(command.equals("quit")) {
        System.exit(0);

    }
    System.out.println("Parameter 1:");
    boolean parameter1=eingabe.nextBoolean();
    if(command.equals("!")) {
        System.out.println(!parameter1);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Parameter 2:");
    boolean parameter2=eingabe.nextBoolean();
    if(command.equals("&&")) {
        System.out.println(parameter1&&parameter2);
    }else if(command.equals("||")) {
        System.out.println(parameter1||parameter2);
    }
eingabe.close();  
   }
}
```

Comment: Ask for a string, and check if it is equal to "t" or "f", just like you're doing with your commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write a little method, something like:

```
boolean customParseBoolean(String input) {
  if ("t".equals(input)) {
    return true;
  } else if ("f".equals(input)) {
    return false;
  }
  // You don't have to throw an exception on invalid input; just an example.
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input: " + input);
}
```

and then invoke this something like:

```
boolean parameter1 = customParseBoolean(eingabe.nextLin());
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter which way you do it, but below should work for your example. It just doesn't cover the case when the input is malformed

```
String parameterString1 = eingabe.next();
boolean parameter1 = !command.equals("f");

String parameterString2 = eingabe.next();
boolean parameter2 = command.equals("t");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can always cross verify the user input in if() condition. create a boolean value with false by default, if the user types t make that boolean as true and vice versa.

or else u can use switch statements